# Retrieving a data-attribute from a clicked element that triggered an event of another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I'm busy on a little jquery mobile webapp with a couple buttons and a popup. The buttons have a `data-id` attribute with an ID. When I click a button then a popup will open, but I have no idea how I get the `data-id` value..

The popup content will be set when the `popupbeforeposition` event will be called. This content will be retrieved via an ajax call with the ID (from the button; `data-id`).

I have create a JSFiddle with a simple version of the webapp: http://jsfiddle.net/yW2PZ/1/

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="popup" id="media-edit-file" data-overlay-theme="a">
            Popup
        </div>

        <a data-id="1" href="#media-edit-file" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup">click me</a>
        <a data-id="2" href="#media-edit-file" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup">or me</a>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).on('popupbeforeposition', '#media-edit-file', function(event, ui)
{
    // how do I get the data-id value.. ?
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider binding your handler to the `click` event of the `a` tags instead. This way, the `data-id` attribute will be accessible through the `$(this)` object of the callback function. You can then open the popup programmatically with the `popup()` method.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event, ui) {
    var data_id = $(this).data('id');
     // ... fetch the popup's content ...
    $('#media-edit-file').popup('open');
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yW2PZ/2/)**

---

**A little more about accessing HTML5 data-attributes**

Note how the `data-id` attribute is accessed with the `data()` method as `id`, since the `data-` prefix is omitted when HTML5 attributes are automatically added by jQuery to the element's `data()` object. For instance, this also means `data-rel` would also be accessible with `data('rel')`. For more about the `data()` method see the [jQuery Manual](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is this:

```
    $(document).on("click","a",function(event,ui){
       var data_id=$(event.target).attr("data-location");
       ...
     }
```